# RoR: attr_encrypted is not saving data on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, attr-encrypted

I'm using `attr_encrypted` in rails 3.2.13 to encrypt a column. For that, in my model I have the following:

`attr_encrypted :social_security_no, :key => 'a secret key'`

The app does not save neither `social_security_no` nor `encrypted_social_security_no` on database.

I also tried `spectator-attr_encrypted` gem. But, now it's giving the following error:

`/home/ashish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@lendty/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in 'method_missing': undefined method 'attr_encrypted' for #<Class:0x0000000824f768> (NoMethodError)`

So, is there any way to get rid of this problem? Or, is there a forked version of the gem which works fine with Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0.0?

And, this is my model:

```
class Lender < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend SignUpCounter
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :evening_phone, :daytime_phone, :social_security_no
  attr_encrypted :social_security_no, :key => '3243serw54325325435sdrtf34453454325sdt346546'

  # Validations
  validates_uniqueness_of :social_security_no, :email

  # Geocoding 
  geocoded_by :current_sign_in_ip
  after_validation :geocode

  # Associations
  has_many :loans
  has_many :borrowers, :through => :loans

  # Scopes
  scope :verified, where(verified: true)

  def full_name
    first_name.to_s + " " + last_name
  end

end
```

Comment: Please add the complete model.rb file.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question so, please refer the question for model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but i think the issue is in the validates_unqiueness_of. One of my co-workers solved this by writing his own validation against it.

```
validate :must_have_a_valid_email


def must_have_a_valid_email
  if email.present?
    leaders = Leader.where(:encrypted_email => Leader.encrypt_email(self.email))
    leaders = leaders.where('id != ', self.id) if self.persisted?
    self.errors.add(:email, "This email address is in use") if leaders.count > 0
  end
end
```